# Receiving multicast Ethernet frames

Tags: python, networking, multicast, ethernet

How can I listen for raw Ethernet frames addressed to a multicast MAC address (eg `77:77:77:77:77:77`) in Python?

I'm listening for raw frames like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_TYPE))
s.bind(("eth0", 0))
s.recv(2048)
```

I can see the frames arriving on `eth0` using `tcpdump` but the above code does not see them.  I think I need to tell the kernel that I'm interested in the multicast MAC address they're sent to but don't know how.

The Ethertype field is set to a non-standard value and the frame content is not a published protocol.

Comment: Multicast is dropped by the interface unless you have subscribed to the multicast group.

Comment: @RonMaupin - that's what I guessed.  But I can't spot any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: And, anyway, if it was the interface dropping them, how would tcpdump still see them?

Comment: I had posted an answer showing how to use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to do this, but it doesn't actually work; you do receive the multicast frames, but you receive multicast frames on **every** interface, not just the one you've bound to.  I'll update the question with what I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for LLDP (multicast), turns out that

```
ip link set eth0 allmulticast on
```

or

```
ip link set eth0 promisc on
```

both works for me.

EDIT: found another safe way:

```
ip maddress add 01:80:c2:00:00:0e dev eth0
```

for my case (LLDP). In which the `01:80:c2:00:00:0e` is the destination mac of LLDP packets.

See https://github.com/jjqq2013/simple-lldp-capture-python-script/blob/main/lldp.sh

for your case it should be:

```
ip maddress add 77:77:77:77:77:77 dev eth0
```